# Where can I find a Java library for code highlighting?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a Java library to highlight code. I don't want to highlight Java code. I want a library that will easily allow me to highlight a macro language of my own, in a code editor of my own written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSyntaxPane is decent. Advanced and decent IDEs use either Lexer/Parsers such as Antlr and Javacc or regular expressions. Implementing it correctly is not a trivial task.

As you mentioned "a macro language of my own", I suggest taking a look at [Lexer/Parser generators for Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/parser-generators) and maybe JEdit syntax package source code(google it, reached the maximum hyperlinks) for lexing strategies.

Answer (score 1):

[GesHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) is pretty good. There is a list of highlighters [here](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/11-syntax-highlighters-to-beautify-code-presentation/).

UPDATE: missed that you wanted a java lib. Try [jedit syntax](http://syntax.jedit.org/) package.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the Java port of GeSHi named [JaSHi](http://www.ohloh.net/p/jashi).  It looks like it is a complete rewrite of the popular PHP package, with Java bindings.

Answer (score 0):

[JSyntaxPane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/) may be the way to go. It will highlight a number of languages and is extensible to handle others.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) - it does a lot more than syntax highlighting; in fact, you only have to define a grammar, and it will generate an eclipse editor plugin with outline, syntax highlighting, syntax checking and autocompletion automatically. It could save you a lot of work if an eclipse editor plugin is an acceptable end result for you.